# Drupal: How to add taxonomy dropdowns to faceted keyword search

Tags: drupal, drupal-taxonomy, faceted-search

How can I override the faceted search UI to expose taxonomy dropdowns in the keyword search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use views and expose filters to achieve this. Please see the link below on how to do it:

http://drupal.org/node/554656

Regards,

Karunakar